# Azure Data Factory - WEB activity output won't return JSON

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, sendgrid-api-v3

I am consuming a SENGRID API [SENDERS](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/senders/create-a-sender-identity) trying to do a GET request (https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/senders) and the output is not returning in JSON format.

This is an example of how the data is returning on ADF:

```json
"[{\"id\":1111111,\"nickname\":\"Marketing\",\"from\":{\"email\":\"abc@m.abc.com\",\"name\":\"Marketing\"},\"reply_to\":{\"email\":\"abc@m.abc.com\",\"name\":\"\"},\"address\":\"sometext\",\"address_2\":\"\",\"city\":\"sometext\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"00000\",\"country\":\"ABC\",\"verified\":{\"status\":false,\"reason\":null},\"updated_at\":1111111,\"created_at\":111111,\"locked\":false}]\n"
```

I have tried other APIs and they return JSON, but in this case it's different. I have also tried the API that I am having problems with on Postman it returns a JSON, but I don't know why it'ss not working on ADF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [Documentation](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments), currently web activity in ADF does not support JSON arrays as response.

[image]

That is why it is returning the JSON array as a string. I have tried with a sample JSON array and you can see it returned it as JSON string.

[image]

As a workaround, to get the above string as a JSON array, use `@json()` on the web activity output response string.

```
@json(activity('Web1').output.Response)
```

This will convert the JSON string as JSON. For sample I am storing this in an array variable.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me out.